# SQL Stuff For XML Path with Multiple Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation

I am using SQL Server 2008.  I am attempting to write a select statement using STUFF and FOR XML PATH to create a comma separated string in one field.  There is only ONE record but 31 fields.

I'm pulling the data from 1 table which has a smallint field for each day of the month - 0 means no for that day, 1 means yes.  (I did not design this table and unfortunately I am not allowed to change it.)  Like so:

```
z1st   z2nd   z3rd   z4th   z5th   z6th   z7th   z8th   z9th   z10th
------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
0      0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      1
0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
0      0      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0
0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      1
```

And so on, all the way through z31st.

My statement is passing integer variables @order_snbr and @admin_nbr, which will always return a single row.

```
DECLARE @strSelectedDayList AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @strSelectedDayList = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CASE WHEN td1.z1st = 1 THEN '1st' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z2nd = 1 THEN '2nd' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z3rd = 1 THEN '3rd' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z4th = 1 THEN '4th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z5th = 1 THEN '5th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z6th = 1 THEN '6th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z7th = 1 THEN '7th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z8th = 1 THEN '8th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z9th = 1 THEN '9th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z10th = 1 THEN '10th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z11th = 1 THEN '11th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z12th = 1 THEN '12th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z13th = 1 THEN '13th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z14th = 1 THEN '14th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z15th = 1 THEN '15th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z16th = 1 THEN '16th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z17th = 1 THEN '17th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z18th = 1 THEN '18th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z19th = 1 THEN '19th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z20th = 1 THEN '20th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z21st = 1 THEN '21st' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z22nd = 1 THEN '22nd' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z23rd = 1 THEN '23rd' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z24th = 1 THEN '24th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z25th = 1 THEN '25th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z26th = 1 THEN '26th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z27th = 1 THEN '27th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z28th = 1 THEN '28th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z29th = 1 THEN '29th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z30th = 1 THEN '30th' END
, CASE WHEN td1.z31st = 1 THEN '31st' END
FROM TableDays td1 WITH(NOLOCK) 
WHERE td1.order_snbr = td2.order_snbr 
AND td1.admin_nbr = td2.admin_nbr 
FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM TableDays td2 WITH(NOLOCK)
WHERE td2.order_snbr = @order_snbr
AND td2.admin_nbr = @admin_nbr

PRINT @strSelectedDayList
```

This produces a result like so:

```
1st14th28th
```

What I would like is this:

```
1st, 14th, 28th
```

Any help would be much appreciated!  And if there's a better way to do this (without STUFF or FOR XML PATH) I'm happy to switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a another approach

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([z1st] varchar(50),[z2nd] varchar(50),[z3rd] varchar(50),[z4th] varchar(50),[z5th] varchar(50),[z6th] varchar(50),[z7th] varchar(50),[z8th] varchar(50),[z9th] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
,(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0)
,(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0)
,(1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
,(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)

Select A.*
      ,C.* 
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast((select A.* for XML Raw) as xml) ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select S = Stuff((Select ', ' +replace(Item,'z','')
                 From (
                        Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                         From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                         Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') like 'z[0-9]%'
                           and attr.value('.','varchar(max)') =1
                      ) C1
                 For XML Path ('')),1,2,'') 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: This is really clever!

Comment: @n8wrl  Shhhh... Don't tell my wife.  She'll want me to do stuff.

Comment: @MFLuder Happy it helped